# What are Popper's views on employment and unemployment?

Tags: political-philosophy, popper

I recently read an interview where Popper ranked his interest in employment above education. Unfortunately, the interview was quite brief and didn't go further into Popper's thinking on this.

**Q. What were Popper's views on employment and unemployment?**

Comment: Is the interview available online? Or a source for it?

Comment: @Frank Hubeny: I ran across it a few weeks ago offline but didn't take a note of the title. For now take it as a place-holder - I'll come back and put some more detail to it.